How to Analyze MongoDb Quey in .NET 8 using LinqKit?
Is there any way to analyze query generated from Linqkit Predicate Builder. I was using Mongodb.Analyzer but found it not working. How can i print equivalent aggregation query of Mongodb in LinqKit?
            Expression<Func<ProductCollection, bool>> filter = BuildFilter(param);
            var expandedFilter = filter.Expand();
            Console.WriteLine(expandedFilter);

Getting Linqkit Expressions in console.

I doubt LINQKit is aware about mongodb (have no proofs though). See my answer with available options here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78406949/how-can-i-see-the-generated-query-when-calling-collection-findasync/78408929#78408929.
but found it not working. - what exactly do you mean here?

Thanks for your response. I did check your answer and downloaded Mongodb.Analyzer before posting this question. What i got bunch of expression generated in console something like below.
profile => ((((((profile.A!= null) AndAlso (profile.A.Name == value(Repository+<>c__DisplayClass23_1).x.ToString())) OrElse ((profile.A != null) AndAlso (profile.A.Name == value(Repository+<>c__DisplayClass23_1).x.ToString())))
and Analyzer didn't show anything.

it's strange, I don't remember such case, it might be because the query you're trying to send is not supported by the driver (effectively what you see is just a raw .net expression form)? Do you see the same behavior for very simple query? Check what you will see for query similar with the one mentioned on the gif image un my answer
